# Open a file after it was created in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I created two classes. The first class takes an image from the working directory and then covert the image from pdf to jpg using wand. The second class takes the created jpg image and then do further manipulations with the image.

Now When I try to run the first class and then the second class right after that; python crashes because the second class is trying to look for the image but it wont find it until it is created.

My question is how can you run the second class but just after the first class is executed.

class1 = imagecreation('image.jpg')
class2 = transformimage()

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. When you reference classes and you import as a module in a different one; the module will get call when is defined if you do not use `if __name__=='__main__':`. By putting this code at the end of the code will only execute the module once it is intended to be executed but not when you import the module. This way you can use the modules by themselves and also to import from other modules.